# How to skip GTID transaction for a particular channel in MyQL?

Tags: replication, skip, slave, mysql-5.7, gtid

We can skip a error in GTID based replication by following steps:

```
STOP SLAVE;
set GTID_NEXT='SERVER_UUID:LAST_TRANSACTION_NUMBER+1' ;
BEGIN; COMMIT; SET GTID_NEXT="AUTOMATIC";
START SLAVE;
```

But if a replication is running with channel information, than how to skip the transaction for a particular channel ?

We can give **"for channel"** keyword in **stop slave** and **start slave**. But how to skip transaction for a particular channel, like in set GTID_NEXT command or what ?

Answer (score 1):

In a replication topology GTID is a global unique identified for any transaction, therefore if transaction is required to skip, specifying channel becomes irrelevant here.
It is similar to MySQL Replication Filters [MySQL 5.7] are global , or in other words, will be applied for all running replication channels